# Sitecore ItemID does it change from deployment to deployment?

Tags: sitecore

I am new to Sitecore and have a basic question around this.  When I create a Sitecore item a Unique ID is created for this item.  Is it ok if I use this item ID in the code to hold a reference to it?  Does this change from deployment to deployment?

Answer (score 2):

If you actually "deploy" your items -using a package or serialization (tool)-, the ID will stay the same and you can keep a reference to it in your code.

It is a good coding practice however not to spread hard-coded guids (as that is what the ID actually is wrapping) around all over your code. So either bundle them somewhere in a piece of code that can easily be deployed without side-effects or put them in a configuration file (but again, bundle them and don't mix with other stuff).

If for some reason the item would be gone some day and you need to re-create it (meaning: the id is changed) or you just need it to point to a new one, you will be grateful that you did keep it somewhere separated ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is Sitecore behaviour to have Sitecore ID like a GUID. It is a very good aproach. The ID of an item can be also use in your C# code

The ID class in Sitecore is used to identify all types of item in Sitecore i.e. content items, templates, media items etc. It is a wrapper around .NET's own System.Guid struct and has a property called Guid which returns a System.Guid. Internally Sitecore stores IDs in it's SQL Server database using the uniqueidentifier type.

For exemple a template is also an item and it has a unique ID. If it wasn't the same ID between environments you need to modify your code between environments.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore ItemID always remain unique. So If you publish the content from your CM server to CD server, Item ID will not change. You can use ItemID as this ensure even if you change the name, you still reference to right Sitecore Content Item.

It is recommended to use some kind of class and put the item id there and reference from there so that in future, if you ever need to change then you change it in one place.

Using directly GUID or any number value for that matter are kind of magic values and is always prone to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer is **yes**, an ID does not change during deployments, so you can hold a reference in your code.

Comment: Then that would be **no**. As in, no it does not change during deployments. But yes, it is ok to use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore Item Id will not change from deployment to deployment, You can use this ID in your code like:

- Creating a class holding IDs
- Or maybe a configuration file